PC with Linux restarts every time I shut down the PC
I have a Lenovo T430s with two hard drives, oOne in the main slot and one with a Hard Disk Drive Adapter in the UltraBay.

On the main hard drive, I have Linux Ubuntu 24.04.
On the other hard drive, I installed Windows 7.

When I shut down the laptop running Windows, it just goes off normally, but when I shut down the laptop running Linux the laptop doesn't really do a restart. The laptop completely goes off, but after about 2 seconds the laptop just starts up. On the first time this problem wasn't there. The laptop just goes off. After a few days the laptop did a "restart" after shutting down, but after the restart I can shut down the PC again and it stays off.
But now every time I try to shut it down it restarts again, and every time after the restart, I need to boot from the Windows hard drive and shut down the PC from Windows.
How can I fix this?

I had a similar problem for a while on my desktop PC (running Ubuntu-based Mint 20.3): at shutdown, it would immediately start again. If I turned off the mains power once it had shut down, I could immediately turn the power on again, without the PC restarting.
The problem has existed for a while, through a number of software updates and kernel versions in the 5.4.0 and 5.15.0 series.
Following the latest software and kernel updates, the problem has gone away.
I am now running kernel 5.15.0-124, but have not run any tests to ascertain whether it was the change to that kernel which was the solution.
I hope this information will help.

OP is using 24.04, which comes with a 6.8 kernel

But the problem is, that im not on a Desktop PC, where I just can turn off the power. Im on a Laptop. So I have just 2 seconds to remove the battery xD. But a long time ago, I want to install an application via the terminal, but it doesnt work well as it is on the website, so I try a command  that, I think, automatic repairs broken packages. After that command running, the system stays off. But a few days later, this bug comes back, without any updating.
